# Adding textview content to array via button click

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I have a view with a textview, I want to add the content of the textview to an array via a button and then display it in a list view on another view. I also want to add multiple items to the array and be able to remove the from the array too.

In other words my goal is to have a contacts page where I can add the number to a favourites page and view my favourite numbers.

Thank you

Comment: have you try any thing. Show here.

Comment: A single textView content to an array ? or each textView content add as an item to an array ?

Comment: A single textView, I have populated a listview with names using Parse, when a name is selected I am navigated to a view which includes the contacts name and number, on that view I have a button, when this button is clicked I was to add the name to a favourites list. To add the name to the array I am using: `Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayList.add(name);
            }
        });`